# On vector space $V = R3[X] $ the mapping $°$ is defined with p ° q = p(-1)q(-1) + p(0)q(0) + p(-3)q(-3)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that dot product is defined with °.

Let p = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx  + d.

I get that for b = 4a and c = 3a
p ° p is 0 and p isn't 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: p ° p = (-a+b-c+d)^2 + d^2 +(-27a+9b-3c+d)^2 =0 . We have:  -a+b-c =0 and -27a+9b-3c =0 ant then I just solve the system

Comment: Are you sure it's $\Bbb{R}_3[X]$. It should be $\Bbb{R}_2[X]$. Because in this case $p(-1)=p(0)=p(-3)=0$ means $p=0$ the null polynomial

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I feel like I'm missing something . Original comment seems to imply that proof is fairly trivial

Comment: @Gregory My bad. You and marwalix are right.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has answered this question yet, and I'm in full procrastination mode, I'll provide an answer.

Yes, you are right, this is not an inner product. Suppose we have a cubic polynomial $p$. Then
$$p \circ p = 0 \iff p(-1)^2 + p(0)^2 + p(3)^2 = 0 \iff p(-1) = p(0) = p(-3) = 0.$$
Recall the factor theorem. The above condition is equivalent to $p(x)$ being divisible by
$$(x + 1)x(x + 3) = x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x.$$
In particular, since $p$ is cubic, we must have $p$ take the form
$$p(x) = a(x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x)$$
for some constant $a$. So, $p \circ p = 0$ if and only if $p$ takes the above form. It's worth noting that this is precisely the solution set you described.

This gives us plenty of non-zero solutions (by simply choosing $a \neq 0$), and means $\circ$ doesn't fit the definition of an inner product.

As marwalix suggests, this question probably contains a typo, and the space $\Bbb{R}_2[X]$ is likely intended instead. Similar logic applies to say that $p(x)$ must take the form
$$p(x) = (x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x)q(x)$$
for some polynomial $q$. But, if $q \neq 0$, then $p$ is of dimension at least $3$, which contradicts its degree being at most $2$. Thus $q = 0$, and hence $p = 0$.

Alternatively, we still have the condition $p(-1) = p(0) = p(-3)$, and quadratic, linear, and non-zero constant polynomials have at most $2$ roots. Thus, $p$ must be the zero polynomial.

The other conditions are straightforward to verify with this correction, so $\circ$ is an inner product on $\Bbb{R}_2[X]$.